# How to add an ObjectNode into another ObjectNode as a child using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson, fasterxml

I have the below ObjectNode.

```
handlerObjectNode -> {"Info":{"Brand":{"BrandName":"TOP OF THE WORLD"}}}
```

I have another ObjectNode in the following format.

```
fieldObjects -> {"Description":"REGULAR BR"}
```

How can I create the below ObjectNode from the above two?

```
{
   "Info": {
       "Brand": {
           "BrandName": "TOP OF THE WORLD"
       }
   "Description": "REGULAR BR"
   }
 }
```

I tried the below code.

```
handlerObjectNode.setAll(fieldObjects);
```

But it results in the following ObjectNode.

```
{
   "Info": {
       "Brand": {
           "BrandName": "TOP OF THE WORLD"
       }
   },
   "Description": "REGULAR BR"
 }
```

I am using the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode from Jackson. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try .. root.with("Info").put("Description", "REGULAR BR");  for more [info](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel)

Comment: @Onkar That worked! thanks mate. Please put this as the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This,

```
  root.with("Info").put("Description", "REGULAR BR");
```

For more info, click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model).

Comment: Link is not available now. Refresh it, please!

Comment: What if the `fieldObjects` is complex nested json instead of single key value pair?

Comment: This answer is not for question asked. Asked how to add object, while the answer is how to add just string.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//create root node
ObjectNode rootNode =  mapper.createObjectNode();

root.put("key1", "value1");
jsonObject.put("key2", "value2");

jsonObject.putArray("array2").add("item1").add("item2").add(12); //tuple
// create child node
ObjectNode childNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        childNode.put("name", "Hungbeo");
        childNode.put("age", 12);

// add childNode to rootNode
rootNode.set("user", childNode);

System.out.println(rootNode.toString());
```

Output:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","array":["item1","item2",12],"user":{"name":"Hungbeo","age":12}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Extract the `Info` object and add the `fieldObjects` to that:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode handlerObjectNode = (ObjectNode) om.readTree("{\"Info\":{\"Brand\":{\"BrandName\":\"TOP OF THE WORLD\"}}}");
ObjectNode fieldObjects = (ObjectNode) om.readTree("{\"Description\":\"REGULAR BR\"}");

ObjectNode info = (ObjectNode) handlerObjectNode.path("Info");
info.setAll(fieldObjects);
```

Results in the following output:

```
{
  "Info" : {
    "Brand" : {
      "BrandName" : "TOP OF THE WORLD"
    },
    "Description" : "REGULAR BR"
  }
}
```